# Why does my cellular data connection keep dropping on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cellular-data, internet-sharing, cellular-carriers

I have an iPhone 6 and recently I have been having issues with my data. Either the connection randomly drops or becomes so slow its unusable. This is very frustrating because my iPhone's hotspot is used to connect all my devices to the internet.

Usually when this happens, turning my data on and off will temporarily fix it. If that fails, turning airplane mode on and off sometimes works, but these are both temporary solutions and neither are very reliable.

As you can see from the screenshots below, when doing a ping test its dropping packets. When doing a speedtest it shows my connection being very slow.

[image: this is a screenshot of a speedtest I did with Google's speedtest]
[image: This is a screenshot of a ping test I did using the app Fing]

Can anyone tell me if this issue is caused by my phone or my network provider? also could anyone advise me on how I can stop issues like this from happening in the future or possible how to increase my data speeds?

Comment: Well You're living in a poor network coverage zone itself. there's only one out of four  in the coverage indicator. That doesn't warrant such periodic drops but definitely makes things worse.

Comment: Is the SIM card the same age as the phone? SIMs have changed a lot in 5 years, talk to your provider & get a new one.